# (iphone) where is "Reject Binary" button?

Tags: iphone, appstore-approval

I just submitted my app for test purposes

(seems like you need to submit/reject the binary to test in-app-purchase)

http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/in-app-purchases-a-full-walkthrough/

I submitted through xcode4 organizer "submit" button.(and it completed successfully)
When I look at my app page in itunes-connect, it's still waiting for upload and there's no "reject binary" button.

Does this status change from "waiting for upload" -> "waiting for review" takes a while?
I need to reject this binary since it's not fully ready yet, and in a panic.
Any prompt response would be appreciated

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Log in To iTunes connect --> Manage your Application --> Click on your Application --> Again Click on your Application Icons --> Binary Details --> Reject Binary button Right top side.

[image]

Hope this help you.

See I have one app in Waiting for Review status and still I have Binary details option and you can reject your binary from there. See attached screenshot. 
[image]

Comment: I don't see the "Binary Details", just "version summary" and "status History", although my organizer shows "status Submitted"

Comment: You need to login here https://itunesconnect.apple.com Not in Organizer. Log in and follow steps which I gave you.

Comment: Sorry I read it now. You don't need to submit binary in order to test In app purchases. Let me check and will get back to you soon. How to reject if it is in waiting for review.

Comment: I think organizer didn't submit the application, "submitted" message was bogus.(due to the fact that I replaced "application loader" for some reason. I completely removed xcode/sdk and reinstalled and organizer is uploading it for a long time.

Comment: So what is the status now ? Are you able to reject and upload new binary ? Let me know.

Answer (score 3):

The "Binary Details" button will not appear while the app state is "Upload Received".
You need to wait until the app state changes to "Waiting for Review".
Sometimes that can take as long as 10-15 minutes.